# Listing inside tabularx?

Tags: listings, tabularx

I have a tabularx environment where I want to put an `lstlisting` into. But Latex fails to compile it. Testcase:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
 First column &
 \begin{lstlisting}
  Sample text
 \end{lstlisting} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I always get a `! Argument of \lst@next has an extra }`. Two questions:

1. What's causing it?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Crosslink: Related questions on the topic of verbatim inside tabularx: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499125)
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578262)
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60852)
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447911)
[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655431)
[6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294722)
[7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671310)
[8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119842) (remark: last one has my answer using a "general" approach using my `cprotectinside` package)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
 First column &
\begin{lstlisting}^^J
  Sample text^^J
\end{lstlisting} \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Generally speaking, all verbatim-like commands and environments cannot be directly used in parameters of other commands. In `tabularx` environments, `X` columntype works actually as macro arguments(it reads the cell contents into boxes first). `listings` package partially fixes it, but still has some limits. See "5.1 Listings inside arguments" of [manual of `listings`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Oh thanks. I read the listings doc at the end, but I forgot to put "^^J" also after the first brace!

Comment: What does the `^^J` literal you appended do? It fixed my custom command to have code listings inside `bclogo` text boxes. Thanks!

Comment: What is that `^^J` ? Is this a symbol ?

Comment: @nowox `^^J` is a line feed

Comment: This does work, but it also adds additional empty lines before and after the listings' contents, thereby breaking the vertical alignment in the table cells. Any ideas if this can be avoided?

Answer (score 11):

1. `tabularx` has to read its content before the macros are executed, so it doesn't support verbatim code.
2. Do the listing outside `tabularx`

   a) Use an external file with `\lstinputlisting`. This can be done in combination with `filecontents` to generate this file automatically:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
   \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

   \usepackage{tabularx}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{filecontents}

   \newsavebox\mybox
   \begin{document}
   % Writes content to temp file
   \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.abc}
    Sample text
   \end{filecontents*}
   % Or just add the 'listings' environment here
   % and use `\input` instead.

   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    First column &
    \lstinputlisting{\jobname.abc} \\
   \end{tabularx}

   \end{document}
   ```

   b) Store the listing in a box and use the box inside `tabularx`:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
   \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

   \usepackage{tabularx}
   \usepackage{listings}

   \newsavebox\mybox
   \begin{document}
   \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
    \begin{lstlisting}
      Sample text
    \end{lstlisting}
   \end{lrbox}

   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    First column &
     \usebox\mybox \\
   \end{tabularx}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: I see now what the advantage of putting listings in separate files are. I had no idea :) I tried using a box to put it outside, but sadly the width of the box will be wrong when the listing is rendered into the box :)

Comment: @Johannes: this might be fixable by using some of the many options of `listings` or surrounding `listings` with a `minipage` environment with a suitable width.

Comment: I don't know the width of the X table in advance :(