# lstlisting-environment not available within tabularx-environment

Tags: listings, tabularx

Please consider the following example. Does anyone has an idea why I cannot use the `listings`-environment within the `tabularx`-environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{foo}{\tabularx{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}}{\endtabularx}
\newcommand{\M}{\textit{Mathematica }}
\newcommand{\C}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\newcommand{\LongText}{This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}
Whatever & \LongText \LongText \\
Something else & \LongText \LongText \\
Code & \begin{lstlisting} for i=0 do... \end{lstlisting} 
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

`tabularx` environment body is grabbed as a macro argument so it can do trial settings at different widths, `listings` is a verbatim-style thing, and verbatim-style things never work in macro arguments.

`tabularx` has some code so that `\verb` sort of works, but anything more complicated is doomed.

You can however do this

```
\setbox0\vbox{\hsize5cm
\begin{lstlisting}
for i=0 do...
\end{lstlisting}}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}
Whatever & \LongText \LongText \\
Something else & \LongText \LongText \\
Code & \usebox0
\end{tabularx}
```

But you have to know in advance the width you want (or do some more complicated thing that queries tabularx to get the width then sets the listings in a box then  does tabularx again.  Note I added `\noindent` in front of your table otherwise you get overfull box warnings in your MWE as  full width table + paragraph indent comes to more than full width.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel thanks was just fixing it but egreg beat me to it:-)