# how to use fancyvrb Verbatim in tabularx?

Tags: minipage, tabularx, fancyvrb

When using `tabular` and `p` it is possible to insert `Verbatim` block in a table using minipage

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{|p{2in}|p{3in}|}
\hline
col 1 & \begin{minipage}{3in}
         \begin{Verbatim}
             test
         \end{Verbatim}
        \end{minipage}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

However, I use `tabularx` and use `X` instead of `p` for that column. But this does not work

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{|p{2in}|X|}
\hline
col 1 & \begin{minipage}{4in}
         \begin{Verbatim}
             test
         \end{Verbatim}
        \end{minipage}
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Error is

```
>pdflatex foo.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
.....
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
)) (./foo.aux)
! Argument of \FV@BeginScanning has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \end{tabularx}
```

At first I thought may be I need extra `{}` around the minipage, but that did not help

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{|p{2in}|X|}
\hline
col 1 & {\begin{minipage}{4in}
         \begin{Verbatim}
             test
         \end{Verbatim}
        \end{minipage}
        }
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Next, I removed the `{}` and replaced `X` by `p` so now it is the same as `tabular`, but this also did not work:

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{|p{2in}|p{3in}|}
\hline
col 1 & \begin{minipage}{3in}
         \begin{Verbatim}
             test
         \end{Verbatim}
        \end{minipage}       
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Next, I put back the `{}` and kept `p` in there, but this did not work either

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{|p{2in}|p{3in}|}
\hline
col 1 & {\begin{minipage}{3in}
         \begin{Verbatim}
             test
         \end{Verbatim}
        \end{minipage}       
        }
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

**question is: How to use `Verbatim` in `tabularx` ?**

Assuming it is possible with a magic trick, I'd like to use `X` actually instead of `p` since I want to tell it to use all the remaining space left.

But with `minipage` it needs a width, but when it is in an `X` column, I do not know the width of that column.  How to handle that minipage wants width value, but it is sitting in an `X` column ?

But first, I'd to know even if `Verbatim` is possible inside `tabularx`

Comment: Short answer: you don't. `tabularx` allows only a restricted form of `\verb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer no it's not possible (as documented) `tabularx` reads its body as a macro argument and you can't use `verbatim` in a macro.

what you can do is

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}


\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
         \begin{verbatim}
             test \ $ {
         \end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|p{3in}|}
\hline
col 1 & \usebox\mybox
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent X\dotfill X



\end{document}
```

I assume you didn't really want `\paperwidth` as the width and also you have to have an `X` column otherwise `tabularx` can not do anything about the target width you supply.

Answer (score 0):

Just come across this question. Using my `cprotectinside` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cprotectinside}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\cprotectinside{@}`
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|p{3in}|}
\hline
col 1 & @\begin{minipage}{3in}
         \begin{Verbatim}
             test \ $ {
         \end{Verbatim}
        \end{minipage}@
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
`

\end{document}
```

Same assumptions as in David Carlisle's answer apply.

Output is as you expect:

[image: output image]

Note that the normal `\verb` cannot be used here, because `tabularx` environment redefines it to "intentionally" make it more limited. But if you insist, there's a workaround `\let\normalverb\verb` then use `\normalverb`, see my [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671330/250119) for an example.