# Why doesn't upquote work with tabularx?

Tags: tabularx, verbatim

Why doesn't `upquote` work with `tabularx`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
This works:

\begin{tabular}{c}
  Inline \verb|`code`| \\   
\end{tabular}

This doesn't work:

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
  Inline \verb|`code`| \\   
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also the warning:

```
\verb may be unreliable inside tabularx
```

For my actual case, I solved using `\textasciigrave` from `textcomp` package. Is there a quicker method?

Comment: In the case of this example `\verb` does not include any special character, so you could just use `\texttt` instead which does not have this issue.

Comment: @HenriMenke With `\texttt{...}` the backticks are not backticks...

Comment: Indeed, I was typesetting the file with LuaLaTeX where this problem doesn't occur at all (no need for `upquote` in the first place).  One more reason to switch to LuaTeX `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Henri Menke mentions in his answer, `tabularx` scans the whole body of the `tabularx` environment and thus fixes catcodes. `\verb`, on the other hand, relies on changeable catcodes to work properly. As a workaround `tabularx` provides a version of `\verb` that works in simple cases but has several flaws (see [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) for the full list), hence the warning you get.

The `upquote` package changes an internal `\verb` macro that makes `'` and `` ` `` active and let them expand to their respective glyph representations. As mentioned, catcode changes are not available with `tabularx`, but we can still extend the `\verb` alternative it provides:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter

\let\@upquote@quote=\textquotesingle
\let\@upquote@grave=\textasciigrave
\ifx\encodingdefault\upquote@OTone
  \ifx\ttdefault\upquote@cmtt
    \def\@upquote@quote{\char13 }
    \def\@upquote@grave{\char18 }
  \fi
\fi

\def\@upquote@repl#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\@upquote@repl@#1\@end\fi
}
\def\@upquote@repl@#1#2\@end{%
  \if#1`\@upquote@grave\else
    \if#1'\@upquote@quote\else#1\fi
  \fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\@upquote@repl@#2\@end\fi
}

\begingroup
\catcode`\*=\catcode`\#
\catcode`\#=12
\gdef\TX@vfirst{%
  \if\@tempa#%
    \def\@tempb{\TX@v@#}%
  \else
    \let\@tempb\TX@v@
    \if\@tempa\space~\else
      \expandafter\@upquote@repl\expandafter{\@tempa}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \@tempb
}

\gdef\TX@v@hash*1##*2{%
  \@upquote@repl{*1}%
  \ifx*2\relax\else#\expandafter\TX@v@hash\fi*2%
}
\endgroup

\makeatother

\begin{document}
This works:

\begin{tabular}{c}
  Inline \verb|`code`| \\
\end{tabular}

This works now, too:

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
  Inline \verb|`code`| \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

First, we set up `\@upquote@quote` and `\@upquote@grave` to map to the upright glyphs of `'` and `` ` ``, respectively. Next comes the definition of a helper macro `\@upquote@repl` that replaces each occurence of `'` and `` ` `` in its argument text by the corresponding glyphs.

Now we can adjust `\verb`s internal helper macros at the right places to apply `\upquote@repl` before the final output is printed. Turns out that we need to change `\TX@vfirst`, which has some special treatment for the first verbatim character, and `\TX@v@hash`, which processes the rest of the text. The result is as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`tabularx` collects its body as an argument and therefore tokenizes the input.  This breaks verbatim material, similar to why `` \section{\verb|`code`|} `` will not work.  The only possibility to forward verbatim material into floating arguments is by saving it in a box first.  In the case of `tabularx` you will also have to `\copy` rather than `\box` because of the multi-pass nature of the algorithm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
This works:

\begin{tabular}{c}
  Inline \verb|`code`| \\   
\end{tabular}

This doesn't work:

\setbox0=\hbox{\verb|`code`|}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
  Inline \copy0 \\   
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```