# \verb with % in tabularx

Tags: tabularx, verbatim

Is there any way of typesetting the % symbol in \verb within a tabularx-cell?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

    \verb|b%a|

    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \verb|b%a| & a
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
        \verb|b%a| & a \\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In `tabularx` the body of the environment is already read and therefore tokenised. The category code changes of `\verb` can't be applied inside of it. Therefore, you'd have to change the catcode of `%` before the `\begin{tabularx}`, this means that you can't put comments there, too. You could do so by putting `\begingroup\catcode\`\%=12` prior to the `\begin{tabularx}` and `\endgroup` after `\end{tabularx}`.

Comment: Footnote on page 2 of the manual for `tabularx`: Since Version 1.02, `\verb` and `\verb*` may be used, but they may treat spaces incorrectly, and the argument can not contain an unmatched `{` or `}`, or a `%` character.

Comment: why not `\texttt{b\%a}` why `\verb` ?

Comment: I opted for `\verb` to avoid the need of escaping all those %s etc. in the code code extracts that I was pasting, but you're right of course, I did end up using `\ţexttt` then.

Comment: @egreg you're right of course, I should have checked the manual first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer: If you don't need comments inside of the body of `tabularx` you can turn the `%` char into a character which can be input directly. If you need comments you can turn another character which you don't need there into the comment char with

```
\category`\<char>=14
```

Just replace `<char>` with a single character which should be the comment character. In the example below I used `#` for the comments inside of `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

    \verb|b%a|

    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \verb|b%a| & a
    \end{tabular}

    \begingroup
    % use `%' as a normal character and `#` as comment character
    \catcode`\#=14
    \catcode`\%=12
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
        \verb|b%a| & a \\ # this is a comment
    \end{tabularx}
    # \endgroup ends the scope of our category changes, so afterwards `#' is
    # again the parameter character and `%' the comments character
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]