# Why \verb@{@ doesn't work with tabularx

Tags: tabularx, verbatim, braces

In this example `tabular` environment works fine, but `tabularx` produces an error.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
    \verb@{@ & cell2 \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX lX}
    \verb@{@ & cell2 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The error is

> ```
> File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
> ```

Comment: this is documented in the tabularx documentation, the body of tabularx is the argument of a macro, and verb does not work in macro arguments, use `\texttt{\{}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you please turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but this one works all right `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}\verb@\0@\end{tabularx}`?

Comment: see the tabularx manual there is a simple version of verb, for tabularx that can cope with simple strings, but can not do hard things like a mis-matched brace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is documented in the tabularx documentation, the body of tabularx is the argument of a macro, and verb does not work in macro arguments, use `\texttt{\{}` (a simple version of verb is implemented for tabularx but can not take a mis-matched brace.