# Lstlisting/Verbatim inside tabularx environment?

Tags: listings, tabularx, verbatim

I noticed that a `\lstlisting` inside a tabularx doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\let\code\lstinline

\begin{document}

% It does work
\begin{tabular}{|*3{>{}l|}} \hline
\code!\begin{center}! & \code!\centering! & \code!\begin{raggedleft}! \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

% It doesn't work
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|*3{>{}X|}} \hline
\code!\begin{center}! & \code!\centering! & \code!\begin{raggedleft}! \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \begin 
l.16 \end{tabularx}
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: see the tabularx documentation: verbatim is not supported

Comment: Yeah, I saw this, any alternative?

Comment: you never need `tabularx` for tables such as `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|*3{>{}X|}} ` as you know in advance the column width so you can use `tabular` with p columns